# What is the contradiction of statement "if $n^2$ is odd then n is odd"

Tags: proof-techniques

In my opinion the contradiction should be-: If $n^2$ is even then n is even. But it is written in my discrete mathematics book that, "n is even then $n^2$ is odd". How do we find contradiction statement?

This is what is written in my textbook.
[image]

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material, including that screenshot: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook shows an example of using a proof technique called "proof by contradiction".

Basically, if you want to prove $A\rightarrow B$, then this technique says: "assume that $B$ **doesnt** hold, but $A$ **does**. From here, we want to derive a contradiction (i.e, we want to derive some statement that is clearly nonsense)".

In this case, $A$ would represent the statement that $n^2$ is odd, and $B$ the statement that $n$ is odd.